# Angular 4 router.navigate not processing route correctly

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using an Angular 4 router.  In index.html I have:

```
<base  href= "/">
```

I have an app.component.ts that contains the following:

```
<div class="content-wrapper" routerLink=“/home” routerLinkActive="active">
    <div class="centered-content">
        <div class=“home-block">                        
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The app-routing.module.ts contains the following:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "home",
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [IsAuthenticatedGuard],
    },
    { path: "",
        redirectTo: "/home",
        pathMatch: "full"
    },
    { path: "**",
        redirectTo: "/home",
        pathMatch: "full"
    },
];
```

I am trying to navigate to the "/home" route when the user clicks to go to new/another tab and returns.  To do this, I am implementing a @HostListener as follows:

```
@HostListener("window:focus", ["$event"])
onFocus(event: any): void {
    // Route to home page to run the activate Guard

    this.router.navigate( ["/home"], {relativeTo: this.route})
        .then((value) => console.log("Value " + value))
        .catch((error) => console.log("Error " + error));
}
```

The HostListener is working but the.router.navigate.. is not

The value returned (.then((value) => ..) is always null except when I put in "" or "root/home" which triggers the empty path or the wildcard path respectively.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can navigate to the current page preferably using a relative path?

Comment: I believe you may want to remove the `/` from the links.

Comment: All of them or specific ones?

Comment: This information might help you: https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate

Comment: I would remove all of them, I do not use a `/` whenever using the router or routerLink.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of removing the "/" from the router (I assume you meant the router.navigate) and routerLink but I am still getting a value of null from the navigation